# Table border not showing up

Tags: html, css

fiddle link ->  http://jsfiddle.net/TZLE3/

I am trying to add boarder around the first second table but even with border="1" on the second table something in the css is making it not show. but i cant find out why?

thus it should look like this  fiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/bC6BF/

any ideas on how to make the first one look like the second one.?
thanks 
glen

edit.. 
first link has all my css  second link has just the css iam wanting to use for that part of the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class is selected with '.' (Dot) and Id is selected with '#' (Hash). In your css you have given a class .reviewtable and selected it with Id #reviewtable.

By the way Here is the Design you want : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZLE3/5/)

Comment: thanks worked great.. .not sure how i missed that.. but THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Check the following class in your CSS , this makes all the borders value to 0.

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}
```

change it to `border:1` that should do it.